# rsync error on windows with CYGWIN

Tags: linux, windows-10, cygwin, rsync, ubuntu-12.04

I have tried various combination to transfer remote files to local using rsync but failed
This the command I arrived at as correct looking at various sources:

```
$ rsync -vvazh --progress pawan@192.168.0.10:/home/pawan/Documents/test/ .
```

This the error I am getting:

```
opening connection using: ssh -l pawan 192.168.0.10 rsync --server --sender -vvlogDtprze.iLsfxC . /home/pawan/Documents/test/  (10 args)
rsync: pipe: Connection timed out (116)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(59) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Comment: can you connect with openssh ?

Comment: Yes. I am able to connect with openssh. As also I am able to use pscp as well.

Comment: Have you checked that rsync is allowed through the firewall?

Comment: Hmm - No Idea, how do I check that. Should I check it in my windows firewall or server firewall?